# Can Amazon's EKS be used to deploy a Docker image with a J2EE container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, wildfly, scaling, amazon-eks

We're looking at scaling solutions for a J2EE application (running Wildfly 15) on AWS.  Can Amazon's EKS be used to house a Docker image that would contain the Wildfly application server?  The container would point to a MySql RDS instance so the db portion would not need to live in the container.  My question is when creating the Docker container with our Wildfly application, what memory parameters should we be passing to our application?  Presumably the goal of EKS is to create replicas when we max out resources but I'm not clear on how to determine memory considerations.